# How to stop playing the seamless music in my game

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my Main Menu UI scene I have created a GameObject (music_manager) where a script is attached unto it that manages my music to be seamlessly playing even if I enter the next scene (Level Selection UI scene).

This is the code of the music_manager :

```
    void Awake () {

        MainMenuSounnd01();     
 }

public void MainMenuSounnd01()
{

    GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("music");
    if (objs.Length > 1)
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

The Level Selection UI is compose of 7 Buttons, each of them loads different levels of my game through `On Click ()`.

How can I make the music stop whenever I click a button in the level selection scene and play a new background music in the newly loaded scene? Here is a function code attached on my button 01 that loads level 1:

```
    public void Level_1_OnClick()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("myLevel_1")
}
```

Thanks :D

Comment: That's a bad Manager code, it should be a singleton where you can check a box to chose if you want to destroy it or not. (Remove the destroy logic from the function make sound and instead you can make sure if you switch between scenes, to stop the music that is been played.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the music, you need to get a reference to the AudioSource component that is playing the music and call Stop().

```
myGameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
```

To play a new clip, set the clip property to a new track and call Play().

```
myGameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = myAudioClip;
myGameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
```

Comment: I'm also wondering if I can functionally destroy the GameObject that plays the music in the MainMenu scene via button click from Level selection scene.

Comment: @RyRen Is the goal to avoid having multiple instances of the music manager?

Comment: Yes sir @Alex Myers

Comment: If you want to ensure you use the same music manager across all scenes without needing to destroy duplicates, I recommend you remove the manager from your main menu scene's hierarchy and instead instantiate it via code after checking if one already exists. This way you don't have to deal with a new music manager spawning every time you return to the main menu scene. You can check if one exists by getting a reference in your Start function `GameObject.Find("Music_Manager");`, then check if null. If it's null, `Instantiate(musicManagerPrefab, new Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);`

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply destroy your current music manager right before you load your main menu scene. Whatever works best with your current setup.

Comment: Is It possible that I can destroy a GameObject (music manager) from another scene? like for example GameObject on scene 1 then Destroy that destroy GameObject from scene 2 by calling a funtion. :D

Comment: @RyRen You cannot delete objects from another scene, as those objects do not exist if the scene is not loaded.